# Two validation checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to control two checkboxes before validation? When I try it works with only 1, but with 2 I block.

**HTML CODE:**

```
   <div id="form-validation">
   <input class="ident_pro_cgv" id="ident_pro_cgv" name="ident_pro_cgv" value="1" type="checkbox" style="width:20px;">
   <input class="ident_pro_habil" id="ident_pro_habil" name="ident_pro_habil" value="1" type="checkbox" style="width:20px;">  
   <div class='ident_pro_habilME' style="color:#fd0082;"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerButton').click(function(){

        var ident_pro_cgv=$('#ident_pro_cgv').val();
        var ident_pro_habil=$('#ident_pro_habil').val();

        if ($("#ident_pro_cgv:checked || #ident_pro_habil:checked").length == 0){
            $('.ident_pro_habilME').text("Veuillez accepter les conditions générales et confirmer votre habilitation.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**change this to:**

```
if ($("#ident_pro_cgv:checked || #ident_pro_cgv:checked").length == 0){
        $('.ident_pro_habilME').text("Veuillez accepter les conditions générales et confirmer votre habilitation.");
        return false;
    }
```

**this:**

```
 if ($("#ident_pro_cgv:checked").length == 0 || $("#ident_pro_cgv:checked").length == 0){
        $('.ident_pro_habilME').text("Veuillez accepter les conditions générales et confirmer votre habilitation.");
        return false;
    }
```

**[Working  Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNsU4/1/)**

**or this:**

```
 if ($("#ident_pro_cgv:checked, #ident_pro_cgv:checked").length == 0){
        $('.ident_pro_habilME').text("Veuillez accepter les conditions générales et confirmer votre habilitation.");
        return false;
    }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNsU4/)**

Comment: `$("#ident_pro_cgv:checked, #ident_pro_cgv:checked").length` would be better.

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter: no its not. this will not ensure whether both of them are checked or not.

Comment: Compare the two versions: http://jsfiddle.net/zNsU4/, http://jsfiddle.net/zNsU4/1/

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter :good catch...will update the answer nor